# How to use \alphalph package as counter option in \tcbtheorem?

Tags: numbering, counters, tcolorbox

I'm typing some math text, and I am using `tcbtheorem` for proposition/theorem/definition boxes. I am using an `\Alph` which is common to all boxes. Problem is : I have now more than 26 boxes, and the `tcbcounter` is too large for alphabet numeration.
I found that the package `alphalph` allows to convert bigger counters to letters. For example, `\AlphAlph{28}` writes AB.
I tried without success to implement that in the `tcbtheorem` options. Here's my work :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{alphalph}

\newtcbtheorem[auto counter, number freestyle = {\noexpand\alph{\tcbcounter}}]
{mybox}{Theorem}{}{mytheorem}

\newtcbtheorem[auto counter, number freestyle = {\noexpand\AlphAlph{\tcbcounter}}]
{mybox2}{Theorem2}{}{mytheorem2}

\begin{document}

\begin{mybox}{This is my box}{} %This box is working fine
\end{mybox}

\begin{mybox2}{This is my box2}{} %With this box, I got an error
\end{mybox2}

\end{document}
```

Please, help me to find a solution.

Comment: canyoutry `\noexpand\AlphAlph{\the\tcbcounter}}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\AlphAlph` needs `\value{foo}` if the counter is named foo, just `foo` isn't sufficient, so apply

```
number freestyle={\noexpand\AlphAlph{\noexpand\value{\tcbcounter}}}
```

as an option (the `\noexpand` statements are needed to prevent premature expansion, as mentioned in the `tcolorbox` manual (see page 110 of the current manual, regarding the description of `number freestyle`)

In order to show the effect, I used `use counter=foo` instead of `auto counter`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{alphalph}

\newtcbtheorem[auto counter, number freestyle = {\noexpand\alph{\tcbcounter}}]
{mybox}{Theorem}{}{mytheorem}

\newcounter{foo}
\newtcbtheorem[use counter=foo, number freestyle={\noexpand\AlphAlph{\noexpand\value{\tcbcounter}}}]
{mybox2}{Theorem2}{}{mytheorem2}

\begin{document}

\begin{mybox}{This is my box}{} %This box is working fine
\end{mybox}

\setcounter{foo}{100}

\begin{mybox2}{This is my box2}{} %With this box, I got an error
\end{mybox2}

\end{document}
```

[image]